# How to set MQOO_INPUT_EXCLUSIVE option for IBM MQ Connection Factory in Camel Consumer with Spring boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-camel, ibm-mq

I am trying to setup spring boot application that needs to consume messages from an IBM MQ queue while ensuring that only one instance of the application receives all messages to maintain message ordering. To achieve this, I need to configure the Camel consumer to open a connection with the MQOO_INPUT_EXCLUSIVE option enabled.

I have already set up the JmsComponent, MQQueueConnectionFactory and RouteBuilder in my application, but I couldn't find the property key and value to enable the MQOO_INPUT_EXCLUSIVE option for the connection via MQQueueConnectionFactory.

Tried this approach by changing the Default input open option in the queue setting and it works, but is there a way to achieve this by passing this property while opening connection?

I have tried searching online for information on how to set this option, but I haven't been able to find a solution,the results were either not relevant to camel based configuration or those were outdated. Can anyone help me with this? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:** I checked from on my side that setting `MQConstants.MQOO_INPUT_EXCLUSIVE` (package - **com.ibm.mq.constants**) in the method `setMQConnectionOptions(int cTagOpt)` from `MQQueueConnectionFactory` doesn't work at all and throws error.

So, It's impossible to set the `MQOO_INPUT_EXCLUSIVE` via `MQQueueConnectionFactory`.

I have some useful links which will help you to understand why it's impossible and check if this helps.

- [Open Input exclusive option (MQC.MQOO_INPUT_EXCLUSIVE )](http://www.mqseries.net/phpBB/viewtopic.php?t=55218&sid=26556302782b5df6fbf3633524bc8141)
- [Setting MQ exclusive-read client properties in JMS](http://www.mqseries.net/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?p=286663)

Only the option that's available to you is to access queue from queueManager with the openOption as `MQOO_INPUT_EXCLUSIVE`

```
MQQueue queue = queueManager.accessQueue("name-of-the-queue", MQConstants.MQOO_INPUT_EXCLUSIVE);
```

Refer to Java Docs on MQConstants [here](https://www.ibm.com/docs/api/v1/content/SSFKSJ_9.2.0/com.ibm.mq.javadoc.doc/WMQJavaClasses/com/ibm/mq/constants/MQConstants.html).

Comment: Its not working. Getting the following error, when I add   
 
 connectionFactory.setMQConnectionOptions(MQConstants.MQOO_INPUT_EXCLUSIVE);


  Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'TESTQ' - retrying using FixedBackOff{interval=5000, currentAttempts=0, maxAttempts=unlimited}. Cause: JMSWMQ0018: Failed to connect to queue manager 'QM1' with connection mode 'Client' and host name 'localhost(1414)'.; nested exception is com.ibm.mq.MQException: JMSCMQ0001: IBM MQ call failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2046' ('MQRC_OPTIONS_ERROR').

Comment: Thanks for the help and detailed explanation. Was hoping to handle it with camel way of RouterBuilder option itself. Changing to MQQueue based session handling will be too much of change for the application we handle. 

Is there any working example available for consumer setup to continuously listening to messages from queue using  MQQueue approach?

Comment: @Prabu There is an working example here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1526213/ibm-mq-message-listener

Comment: Though the question was specific to creating exclusive connection through camel MQQueueConnectionFactory & RouteBuilder, you answer helps to understand that it can't be done. Hence happy accept it as more helpful answer